# How Can I bypass the GMAIL proxy and make a tracking pixel in 2021?

Tags: php, image, gmail

I want to make a program similar to the chrome extension [mailtrack](https://mailtrack.io).
It can track when a user opens an email, and I want to do the same.

I have made an image on my webserver so that it will open and write to a file whenever it is requested. (e.g a tracking pixel).

This doesn't work, because google proxies, and caches the image; rewriting the url to https://foo.googleusercontent.com/proxy/foobarfoobarfoobar#myoriginalurl.

This causes the request not to be made to my server, but googles.

How can I fix this?

And if it is impossible, ok, but then how would the aforementioned mailtrack work?

My code is:

```
<?php

$file = 'image.png';

$fp = fopen('log.log', 'a');

fwrite($fp, 'Opened' . PHP_EOL);


header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile($file);
?>
```

> When you send an email, Mailtrack automatically adds a tracking pixel (a really small image) to that email. Then, when it is opened the tracking pixel is downloaded and sends a call to our servers to let us know the mail has been opened.

Also,

> Mailtrack is an email tracking tool. It tells you if your emails have been opened or not, and how many times, through its pixel-based tracking system.

Comment: AFAIK the Google image proxy isn't caching it, you will still get a request when the email is opened, it will just mask the location and user agent. Additionally though there is a bot downloading the image as soon as it is received. See this article for details: https://www.gmass.co/blog/false-opens-in-gmail/

Comment: hm, if thats so, that is wierd, because I never recieve a request and the file is never written.

Comment: But then something is weird anyway on your side because regardless of whether a proxy or a browser loads it, you'd get a request

Comment: any fix? like idk

Comment: You need to debug it, for example open the URL yourself anf see whether the file gets created, check the error log on the server, open the email in another client Luke Thunderbird (and dismiss the external content warning), etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it. I use python to do it now.

My server code for others wondering is:

```
import flask
import random

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sig.png')
def sig():
  print(f'Requested {random.randint(1,9999)}')
  return flask.send_file('images/sig.png', 'image/png')

app.run('0.0.0.0', 8080)
```

Comment: But does this solve the actual issue? I've been working on something very similar. The pixel is requested only when the email is opened for the first time and not for the consecutive opens. The gmail proxy caches the image. Is there any work around for this? Making gmail allow the pixel to make a request for all opens.